# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements after Xcode 7.2 update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Today I updated Xcode to version 7.2. When I opened Xcode after the update to do some enhancements to my app, I got build errors about the name of the app, which has an underscore in it (com.company.my_app). So I changed to bundle identifier to `com.company.myapp` (just removed the '_'). I've tried to rename all the `My_app` instances to the name without the underscore.

Now, every time I build the app it works, the build succeeds. But when it has to run the app on the iPhone (which I've previously used), it gives the error `The executable was signed with invalid entitlements`. I've checked the build settings with the provisioning profiles and entitlements and this is the list:

**Code Signing**

- Setting: My_app

**Code Signing Identity**: iOS Developer

- Debug: iOS Developer

  - Any iOS SDK: iOS Developer
- Release: iOS Developer

  - Any iOS SDK: iOS Developer

**Provisioning Profile**: Automatic

- Debug: Automatic
- Release: Automatic

Changing the Code Signing Identity values to anything else I can choose from the menu (I get my own account with my email address, which is the correct one), it gives the following error:

**Failed to code sign "Myapp"**

*Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “ca8f55bc-aa78-445a-aa45-a6a69ff552f7”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and   provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.*

It then shows a dialog asking me to fix these issues, but when I do that (selecting my profile) it just resets the values back to `iOS Developer` and the `Provisioning Profile` settings back to `automatic`. When I try to run the app, it just gives me the same error about the executable being signed with invalid entitlements.

How do I fix this? I just can't install this app on my iPhone and in the simulator it gets stuck at the splash screen. It was working perfectly well before the Xcode 7.2 update.

Comment: did u fix your problem? i need solution too

Comment: I rebuilt the app using Cordova CLI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your bundle identifier is linked to your provisioning profile when you changed it there is now no provisioning profile for your app.

Comment: Change the bundle identifier back to what it was.